# Validation: The following problems were detected JavaFX Project

Tags: java, eclipse, validation

I am working on a javafx project, and I keep seeing the following errors when I drop to compile and run, I am not really sure why. Any tips would be very helpful.

*Update 7/23/14 4:12 PM

Added another pic

[image: Error]

[image]

Comment: Elapse the folding elements, this will provide more information on the errors you get.

Comment: Says missing constraint, then requests I import package javax.xml.bind, however, doesn't seem to solve anything. I import that, and eclipse just asks me to remove unused imports

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420283/launching-plugin-fails-missing-constraint-javax-xml-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself a headache. Delete all the eclipse files. Download eclipse. 10 times faster than messing with some of this stuff.